# perl regex negative set matching string in negative lookahead

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match any set of characters (inside square brackets) other then square brackets (`[^\[\]]+`) -- unless the last part of the string of characters matches `-notme`.

```
perl -sp -e 'if (/\[[^\[\]]+?(?!-notme)\]$/../^no/)
 { print "#"; s/^yes/$VAR/; }' -- -VAR="CHANGED" /tmp/input
```

My input file looks like this:

```
-bash-4.2# cat /tmp/input 
[test-ing]
yes
yes
no
maybe

[test-ing-notme]
yes
yes
no
maybe
```

But my output looks like:

```
#[test-ing]
#CHANGED
#CHANGED
#no
maybe

#[test-ing-notme]
#CHANGED
#CHANGED
#no
maybe
```

My speculation is that the negative set is matching what my negative lookahead should be not matching -- hence my attempt with lazy matching of the negative set, but the result is the same as if it were a greedy match.

My expectation would be that the output would look like:

```
#[test-ing]
#CHANGED
#CHANGED
#no
maybe

[test-ing-notme]
yes
yes
no
maybe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the pattern: `/\[[^\[\]]+?(?!-notme)\]$/` to

```
/\[[^]]++(?<!-notme)]$/
#      ^ ^-------------- a negative loobehind before the closing bracket
#      '---------------- a possessive quantifier to prevent backtracking
```

In this way, you are sure that "-notme" isn't tested at useless positions in the string.

As you can see, it's possible to not escape a closing bracket in a character class if this one is at the first position or immediately after the negation caret.

Comment: Hi Casimir, why `\[(?:[^]]+?(?<!-notme)\])` also work? Instead of `++`, `+?` what is the difference between then? Just got curios as I was testing it on https://regex101.com/r/sV5gF7/1

Comment: @JorgeCampos: `[^]]+` works also too, the only difference is the performance. With a lazy quantifier the lookbehind is tested for each character taken by `[^]]+?` *(until the lookbehind succeeds, but for each character the next token `]` will fail except for the last)*, with a greedy quantifier, the regex engine will try to backtrack to make the pattern succeed. But with a possessive quantifier, no choice, all characters are taken and the regex engine hasn't the right to backtrack.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.